# How can I effectively interview someone remotely for a programming job?

Tags: interviewing

We have a automation engineer contract position open and I'm conducting interviews. Most candidates are out of town and so I cannot reasonably bring them in for a face-to-face interview. I've had issues in the past with overstated resumes so I want to confirm that they have the skills that I need. My attempted solution to this was to get them to actually write some code from scratch so I can see them demonstrate ability. The struggle has been how to best accomplish this. In the past I've set up a scenario on my box and used WebEx, etc. and had them take control. The idea being that I would do all the setup so they didn't have to. The problem with this is that they are trying to type and use the mouse but the lag in the connection makes it difficult and frustrating. I've recently altered my approach and asked them to be prepared to code during the interview... have an environment set up and ready before the call. This has been somewhat more successful but this must be a common problem so I wanted to ask what others are doing to assess programmer skill remotely?

Comment: collabedit.com for one, is designed for this purpose. Take your pick from any number of online, collaborative, code editors.

Comment: Explain the downvote? What am I missing?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere While an in-person interview would be nice, it's not something that my company is willing to pay for. Many candidates are out of state so phone interview is all we have. It's more about how to get the most out of the phone interview.

Comment: I hope the company understands the risks you're taking when trying to interview out of state candidates remotely. Hopefully the money they save will go towards a better internet connection.

Comment: @JeffO They view contract quite different than full time. Contract they are perfectly willing to interview and hire over the phone, if they aren't local. For full time hires, they require in-person interviews as far as I've seen.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere This is a contract position, not full time. I don't control the company's policies. In our area at least, there are very few that are already local so this is the best we can do. If we required a face-to-face before even a contract position hire, we'd never get anyone.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere We are using agencies... still we rarely find someone that is already local. And depending on the agency, their version of "vetting" varies widely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than having a video camera, there's no way to know if the candidate is the one actually doing the typing. I suspected one candidate was on a skype call to get some help with a coding task I gave him as part of the interview. The candidate was clueless, so I cut it short and never hired them.

I think you can give a coding task to do on their own, but put a lot more emphasis on a follow-up phone call or webex to have the candidate explain what they've done and most importantly why.

It's a pleasure to actually watch a really good programmer perform her craft. It just doesn't take long to pick them out. If you can't get them to your office, you just have to use whatever technology you can or you may find your confidence level is going to decline. This is why it's important to build a network with other professionals and get great referrals.

Comment: I agree. That's part of the reason why I like the WebEx interview where I watch them code. They could have someone helping them but if I'm talking to them while they code, I think it makes it less likely that they could get help without me knowing.

Comment: I don't do "watch me code" interviews. Period. I once ended the process at a Fortune 250 company when I realized that the reason why they were having me code on their VM was because they had recording software. I have anxiety that doesn't affect my work even when interacting with people but it goes through the roof when people try to watch me work. I won't do pair programming either. Look, you can pick out someone unsuitable within 2 days of working.Ask me to code something and I'll send it to you. If you need to watch me work, it's over before we start.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep That makes sense but that's the exception rather than the rule. I would try to find something to accommodate as much as possible but it would be hard. The problem that I've found with the people we seem to get is that their resumes are highly inflated... to the point where it's absurd at times. If I let someone write code and send it to me, some/many would take advantage of that and have a friend write it, etc. I also can't hire someone and then fire them 2 days later after they don't work out. Management is going to (rightly) question my hiring/interview process.

Comment: @JeffC That's also why I don't do "direct hire" anymore. It's contract to perm or nothing. Direct hire is like marrying someone after spending a few hours with them. If you married someone after spending the same amount of time you do on pre-employment, you wouldn't be surprised with it doesn't last yet everyone thinks that you can find long-term employees without seeing how they work on a day-to-day basis. When you are able to do that, it isn't because of the process, you just got lucky. Try before you buy. :)

Comment: @ChristopherEstep I agree. This is a contract position... not even contract to hire.

Comment: @JeffC The only kind of "testing" of that sort that I didn't have a problem with was one time I was put in a room by myself and given a task to import something from a text file, filter it out for certain criteria and then output it in a certain way. I was left alone and given whatever time I needed and could look stuff up on the 'net if needed. The interviewer then came in and we did a code review. He was able to learn if I could actually code and got insight as to why I made certain decisions. Took 2 hours and I did get the job. It was a contract.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep - temp to hire is becoming common, but I wouldn't plan on luring away a good programmer from an average job unless you're able to hype your company.